# Firefox add-on to autogenerate passwords in registration forms

Tags: firefox, password-manager

I'm looking for a Firefox add-on to suggest passwords within the registration forms, much like what [Chromium is doing](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/password-generation/):

[image: Chromium suggests a password when focusing the password field in a registration form, and allows to add it to the saved passwords]
<sub>(source: [chromium.org](https://www.chromium.org/_/rsrc/1394745053088/developers/design-documents/password-generation/GenerationUI.png))</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Lastpass](https://lastpass.com/) can do that. It keeps all your website passwords (and more) in one vault and you can (optionally) have it log you in automatically, and for new sites it can generate strong passwords (You set the strength, I recently changed it from the default 12 characters to 15).

[image: Lastpass password generation]

Extended information e.g. [Security Now podcast #256](https://www.grc.com/sn/past/2010.htm)

Comment: This is better than a native solution I guess as it's browser agnostic (also added a pic showing behaviour)